# What is the error in the mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

The error says:

> You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near  'AS counts FROM (`at_shop`) WHERE `shop_status` = 1 AND
>   `shop_customer` = 'on' ' at line 1

This is my query .

```
SELECT *, LENGTH(`shop_update`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`shop_update`, `, `, `))` AS counts FROM (`at_shop`)
```

My Active Record query is :

```
$this->db->select("*,LENGTH(shop_update) - LENGTH(REPLACE(shop_update,' , ','')) AS counts");
$this->db->order_by("counts","DESC");
$this->db->from('at_shop');
```

Any help?

Comment: The quotes are getting replaced by backticks. That is causing an error.

Comment: You need to pass second parameter false in `select()` like `$this->db->select("*,LENGTH(shop_update) - LENGTH(REPLACE(shop_update,' , ','')) AS counts" ,FALSE);` [According to docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: but the output shows counts are 0 (zero)

Answer (score 0):

you are not writing replace clause correctly

you have wrote:-

```
LENGTH(REPLACE(`shop_update`, `, `, `))`
```

Instead Write

```
LENGTH(REPLACE(`shop_update`, ',',''))
```

note-->you are removing comma from `shop_update`